# How do I check if a string starts with two numbers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to take in a str via usr_input = input("Input here: ") and then check if that string starts with two digits.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What have you tried?   `if usr_input[:2].isdigit():`.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Make sure to add `len(usr_input) >= 2` to that test.

Comment: Probably not important for this exercise, but `isdigit()` will return True for more than just base 10 digits. For example: `'6'.isdigit()` -> `True`. `isdecimal()` may be a better choice if you want to limit to 0-9.

Comment: @Mark thank you for that, that helped a lot since I wanted to limit to that

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks! I'm very new to Python and would have forgotten

Comment: @TimRoberts Why do I do :2 btw instead of :1, does it not start at 0? Asking because later I also want to check the fifth and sixth place for digits and now I don't know whether to do [5:6] or [4:5].

Comment: @TheVirtuoso: Slices implicitly begin at one end of the string (the beginning by default, the end if you use a negative step) and they're *exclusive* on the end (so `[:2]` gets index 0 and 1, but not 2). If you want to check index 4 and 5 (the fifth and sixth indices, since we're zero-based) you'd use `[4:6]`, to check index 5 and 6 (the sixth and seventh indices) you'd use `[5:7]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
usr_input = input("Input here: ")
if(len(usr_input) >= 2 and usr_input[:2].isdigit()):
    print('yes') # write your code here
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of variety:

```
import re
string=input()
bool(re.search(r'^\d{2}',string))
```

Comment: For the sake of accuracy: as in the case of `str.isdigit()`, the special sequence `\d` in the regular expression also catches digits that are considered digits in the Unicode table, not just characters from the range from 0 to 9. To limit the search to characters from the range from 0 to 9, one should set the `re.A` flag or use the character class `[0-9]' instead of `\d'.

Answer (score 0):

luckily, there's a method for this.

a solution is

```
def begins_with_two_digits(your_str):
    first=your_str[0]
    second=your_str[1]
    if first.isdigit() and second.isdigit():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

the .isdigit() method will check if the first and second characters are digits.
in practice, though, you want something like this:

```
if your_str[0:2].isdigit():
    #stuff
else:
    #some other stuff
```

Comment: you're quite right, i meant [0:2]

Comment: In the first code there will be an IndexError` if `len(your_str)`<2. There should be a length check, before checking first and second elements.

Comment: And the second is also in need of checking the length first. Try this: `'1'[0:2].isdigit()`

Comment: Do I need to do [0:2] or does [:2] suffice? The other answers all did :2 so that's why I am asking

Comment: @TheVirtuoso: `[:2]` is enough; omitting the beginning of slice index here just means "slice from the beginning of the string".